# thread synchronization problem (with updating a variable sum)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

When I want to update with either synchronized keyword or lock, it works when the sum variable is int but not when it is an Integer object.

code looks like this -

```
public class TestSynchronized {
  private  Integer sum = new Integer(0);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestSynchronized test = new TestSynchronized();
    System.out.println("The sum is :" + test.sum);
  }

  public TestSynchronized() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

    for (int i = 0; i <=2000; i++) {
      executor.execute(new SumTask());
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    while(!executor.isTerminated()) {
    }
  }

  class SumTask implements Runnable {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void run() {
    lock.lock();

      int value = sum.intValue() + 1;
      sum = new Integer(value);

        lock.unlock(); // Release the lock
      }

  }
}
```

Comment: `Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();` you are creating a new Object for every thread

Comment: For this use case, I'd suggest using `AtomicInteger` and `getAndIncrement` or `incrementAndGet`. Then you don't need the locks any more.

Comment: Your incrementing of `sum` would be far more easily (and equivalently) written as `sum++;` (except that you'd then be using cached Integer instances sometimes). Autoboxing does what you are doing here "for free".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've separate `locks` for each of the `SumTask` objects. These objects should share the `locks` instead.

Create a `lock` object once in `TestSynchronized()` method. This should be shared by all the `new SumTask(lock)` objects.

So your `SumTask` class would look like:

```
class SumTask implements Runnable {
    Lock lock;

    public SumTask(Lock commonLock) {
        this.lock = commonLock;
    }

    public void run() {
        lock.lock();

        int value = sum.intValue() + 1;
        sum = new Integer(value);

        lock.unlock(); // Release the lock
    }

}
```

And don't forget to create a `commonLock` object in `TestSynchronized()` method:

```
  Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  executor.execute(new SumTask(commonLock));
```

Comment: OP said "it works when the sum variable is int" I think it is worth pointing out that this is, at best, mere fluke.